# My Android layout is not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to design an UI with 3 elements, one TextView tvStart, one SeekBar sbProgress and one TextView tvEnd.

I want tvStart aligned left and tvEnd aligned right, with sbProgress at the center.
And I want to do everything programmatically!

I have this code:

```
public void MyLayout() {
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);

    TextView tvStart = new TextView(this);
    SeekBar sbProgress = new SeekBar(this);
    TextView tvEnd = new TextView(this);

    tvStart.setText("0");
    tvEnd.setText("100");
    sbProgress.setMax(100);

    layout.addView(tvStart);
    layout.addView(sbProgress);
    layout.addView(tvEnd);

    setContentView(layout);
}
```

But it seems the 3 elements are aligned from left to right and the SeekBar is very short.
Is it possible to do such tings with LinearLayout or do I need to use RelativeLayout?

Comment: set LayoutParameters

Comment: why you wanna do with code??? can't you use XML??

Comment: I like doing it in code because: 1). Only need to change one file, no need to just here and there. 2). if you want to copy the same code to another project, it's more easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void MyLayout() {
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);

    TextView tvStart = new TextView(this);
    SeekBar sbProgress = new SeekBar(this);
    TextView tvEnd = new TextView(this);

    tvStart.setText("0");
    tvEnd.setText("100");
    sbProgress.setMax(100);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams startParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams sbParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    sbParams.weight = 1;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams endParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.addView(tvStart, tvParams);
    layout.addView(sbProgress, sbParams);
    layout.addView(tvEnd, endParams);

    setContentView(layout);
}
```